# Sendkeys doesn't work to dhtml edit control on win xp

Tags: vb6, dhtml, sendkeys

The code below will send the keystrokes to the DHTML edit control on Windows Vista but not on windows xp.

```
DHTMLEdit1.SetFocus
MySendKeys ("zzz")
```

MySendKeys refers to a replacement for VB6 Sendkeys written by [Karl Peterson](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput/) for windows vista and beyond. But I don't think that's relevant because the following code does not work on xp either

```
DHTMLEdit1.SetFocus
SendKeys ("zzz")
```

On windows xp the DHTML edit control is "DHTML Edit Control for IE5" according to the project components window in vb6
On windows vista it's the "DHTML Editing Control" which does not come pre-installed with windows but is [available from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663363.aspx).

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys()` isn't so compatible anymore.  DHTML editor likely has another method of inputting data that doesn't require you to hack something together like that.  For the most part, it's usually a security risk.

Also, it's likely a different control altogether, and it might not even properly respond to key strokes.

Perhaps you can elaborate on what you're attempting - maybe there's a better solution than sending key strokes.

Comment: Thanks but although Sendkeys doesn't work on vista the replacement mentioned does. Also the problem isn't on the newer version of windows it's on xp. I am trying to insert/paste text at the current position in the dhtml control

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this inelegant solution

```
Clipboard.SetText "zzz"
DHTMLEdit1.ExecCommand DECMD_PASTE, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
DHTMLEdit1.SetFocus
```

On vista and later it's effect is the same as sendkeys.

On xp it inserts the text correctly but doesn't leave you 
with a blinking cursor (you have to manually click the control
to resume typing from the keyboard).